# Are there many restrictions in the title? How to know about that?

Tags: discussion, title

For example:

> How to choose between `as you say` and `as one said`

[image]

Comment: The SE machine routines for finding similar questions and identifying 'subjective' questions are notoriously ill-suited to the sorts of question asked here. Usually these prompts are pretty useless.